# regex question: not allow a single dot (allow only if have digit before dot or digit after dot)

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

I would like to allow user to type the following decimal or integer values  (A)

```
.5
0.500
3
0
0.0
30
500000
4000.22
0.
```

This is the following regex that I have used:

```
factor: /^-?\d*[.]??\d*$/,
```

But the problem is that the above regex also allow the following invalid number (B)

```
        . (comment: a single dot )
       00.5 (multiple zeros before dot)
      0000.5
       00 (multiple zeros)
```

Also not allow user type negative values i.e. -3, -0.5

I am trying to modify the above regex to not allow the invalid values at (B), but allows the values at (A)

My attempt which does not work:

```
 factor: /^-?\d*[.]+\d*$/,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
^-?[1-9]*?0?(\.\d+)?$
```

[Example Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OIArgA/1)

Comment: Just edited the question. would like to work for zero with a dot too . Thanks

Comment: @user21 - It doesn't seems intutive to allow `x.` case. __`x.` is not a proper notation__ and is equiv. to whole no. `x`. It seems from another comment that you don't want to show error, but if I change the regex, it could match other incorrect cases!

Comment: I understand x. is not a proper notation but I would like the user to not see the error while typing x., which is why I does not want to show the error for this case. Maybe after user finish typing and if the value is x.,  I will create a function to add x.0 so that it is proper value

Comment: Okay @user21, for your concern, this is your improper regex: `(^-?[1-9]*?0?(\.\d+)?$)|(^\d+\.$)`

Answer (score 3):

you can make use of following expression which evaluates dot on the basis of digits before dot.

```
^-?(((?!00)\d+(?:\.{1}\d*)*)|((?!00)\d*(?:\.{1}\d+)))?$
```

**[Demo link](https://regex101.com/r/OIArgA/3)**

Comment: Just edited the question. would like to work for zero with a dot too . 
The above regex works for all cases, is wondering if it  is possible to reduce the length of the regex?

Comment: for regex to work with zero you can remove `(?!00)` i.e. `^-?((\d+(?:\.{1}\d*)*)|(\d*(?:\.{1}\d+)))?$` ... this regex is long because i have repeated the regex conditionallly on the basis of value before decimal point... not sure if we can reduce it ... I will updated this answer if get any other solution

Comment: Okay I will also try to find any other solution to shorten the regex length.If you know about that, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could match an optional hyphen and then assert that the string does not start with 2 zeroes.

Then match optional digits, an optional dot and match 1+ digits to prevent matching an empty string.

```
^-?(?!00)\d*\.?\d+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `-?` Match optional `-`
- `(?!00)` Negative lookahead, assert not 2 zeroes directly to the right
- `\d*` Match  0+ digits
- `\.?` Match optional `.`
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l6X1PD/1)

```js
const regex = /^-?(?!00)\d*\.?\d+$/;
[
  ".5",
  "0.500",
  "3",
  "0",
  "0.0",
  "30",
  "500000",
  "4000.22",
  ".",
  "00.5",
  "0000.5",
  "00",
  "-4000",
  "-0",
  "-00",
  ".",
  ", ",
  "00.4"
].forEach(s => console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`));
```

Comment: I would also like to allow 0. value (a zero with the dot). Because do not want to show error when user is typing zero with a dot which is equivalent to 0

Answer (score 0):

try this regex `^-?[1-9]*\.?\d+$`

the brackets say that you can have 0 or 1 digit.

Comment: Thanks you. Hi I have just edit my question. Would like to allow more than 1 digit too, but do not want to allow invalid number. So '00' , '.', '00.4' are invalid number

Comment: would like to work for zero with a dot too . Thanks